# How can I get a property value from a style attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="card card-stats" style="background-color:#FF001A">
```

Below I'm fetching the background color-red which is in hex code

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('div').item(0).getAttributeNode('style');
var b = a.getAttributeNode("STYLE").value ;
```

I am confused with the syntax and methods how can we fetch the style attribute value which is having `#FF001A` hex code and store it in a variable using JavaScript?

Later I want to compare that value with Red color and my code will execute further.

Comment: Read the intro articles on SO first. We can't help without any [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also please put some effort into formatting.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to access a DOM element, the simplest being by its ID, like this:

```
<div id="someid" style="background-color: #FF001A"></div>

<script>
  var style = document.getElementById('someid').style;
  alert(style.backgroundColor);
</script>
```

Comment: i have a question with the alert statement as i am dealing with background-color so shall it be alert(style.background-color);

Comment: I have since changed my example to use the background color instead.

Comment: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null.......                                                                                                               var style = document.getElementById("red").style;    this is my code it is giving the above error I gave the id ="red" in the html code                             <div id="red" class="card card-stats"  style="background-color:#FF001A">

Comment: It's hard to say for sure without debugging the code, but you are possibly running the JS before the HTML as finished loading? try running the JS at the bottom, or even better, when the document has finished loading, using a document ready event listener.